# Network Costs Application Design Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, networking

Is it possible to have network costs related to using an application be charged to the company's account and have the user use said application free of charge after the initial download? (All costs related to the usage of data/network will be charged to the company.)

The application will be designed in Flutter. Just want to know if anyone has managed to figure this out. It's more or less like the FNB application where you are permitted to go even if you do not have data.

Any guidelines or sites I can look up will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You would need to work that out with the various data carriers.  Only they can determine which traffic they charge for on their network.